# LinearLayout is null inside button's onClick

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, findviewbyid

I'm trying to hide a linearlayout on a button click and display another linearlayout which is in the same layout file. But the linearlayouts are null inside the onclick of the button.

The `displayLayout` and `editLayout` are null.

```
        displayLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    editLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.editLayout); 
    edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            displayLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
            editLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.editLayout);
            displayLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); //error occurs here
            editLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

Here's the layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.prematixsofs.taxiapp.EditUserDetails">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    >
    <!--Display UserDetails Layout-->

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/displayLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phNo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/edit"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                android:text="Edit"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<!--Edit Layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/editLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editPhNo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editConfirmPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error code **displayLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);**

right code **displayLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.displayLayout);**

you set a not exist id.

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot. I changed the id, but forgot about it and don't know why android studio suggested it while typing even though I removed that id. Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

Just fix your view ID in your code

```
    displayLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.displayLayout);
    editLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.editLayout); 
    edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            displayLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot i changed the id